# Autofac: How to decorate a single component that implements multiple services

Tags: c#, decorator, autofac

Suppose I have a component that implements multiple interfaces:

```cs
public interface IService1 { }
public interface IService2 { }
public interface IService3 { }
public interface ICommonService : IService1, IService2, IService3 { }
public class CoreComponent : ICommonService { }
```

and its decorator

```cs
public class DecoratorComponent : ICommonService
{
    public DecoratorComponent(ICommonService coreComponent) { }
}
```

And then I need to resolve instances of `IService1-3` and `ICommonService` as well.
That's the problem.

Because I'd like to have a single instance of my `CoreComponent` and a single instance of the decorator. But after reading [this issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/963) I understood that this is impossible (as far as I understood).

At least, I want to have a single instance of my `CoreComponent` and multiple decorator instances, as many as the services, decorating that single core component instance.
But when I registered them as following

```cs
builder
    .RegisterType<CoreComponent>()
    .As<ICommonService>()
    .As<IService1>()
    .As<IService2>()
    .As<IService3>()
    .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterDecorator<DecoratorComponent, ICommonService>();
builder.RegisterDecorator<DecoratorComponent, IService1>();
builder.RegisterDecorator<DecoratorComponent, IService2>();
builder.RegisterDecorator<DecoratorComponent, IService3>();
```

and resolve `IService1`, I've got an instance of the decorator, decorating an instance of the decorator, decorating an instance of the core component. That's frustrating.

How to register that decorator properly to have only one level of decorators in my case, and have all the services resolved?

**UPD**: here is the sample code with my registration and the registration in the accepted answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PxjRqf
You can see that strange Autofac behavior when registering as above and how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of register the `CoreComponent` exposed as `IService1`, `IService2` and `IService3`, you could register it only exposed as `ICommonService` and add registrations for the other interfaces forwarding them to an `ICommonService` resolution.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the type as singleton
builder
  .RegisterType<CoreComponent>()
  .As<ICommonService>()
  .SingleInstance();

// Register the decorator only once, for ICommonService.
builder
  .RegisterDecorator<DecoratorComponent, ICommonService>();

// Now, forward service resolution to ICommonService
builder
  .Register(container => container.Resolve<ICommonService>())
  .As<IService1>()
  .As<IService2>()
  .As<IService3>();
```

In the end, no matter what interface you resolve a `CoreComponent` from (either `ICommonService` or any `IServiceX`), Autofac will always end up resolving it from the `ICommonService` registration, which is decorated by the `DecoratorComponent`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Updated the question to show that.